# Git merging two separate repos from the same project, from different points in time

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I've done something like this in the past:

- remove .git directory
- git init
- making commits...

I have a copy of project where I still have old .git directory. How could I incorporate it into new repo? I just want to add this previous history to the repo, as if I never deleted this .git directory.